# D3.js force layout with drag/zoom/pan and join nodes capabilities

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js, drag-and-drop

Basically, what I want to do is to merge this two examples:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708

http://bl.ocks.org/benzguo/4370043

I thought to use a key press to select if I wanted to drag a node, or to draw a line, something like this:

```
function dragstarted( d ) {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();

    if ( d3.event.sourceEvent.ctrlKey ) {
        // drag a line
    } else {
        // drag the node
    }
}
```

The dragstarted function is called on `dragstart` event. In this case, I should stop the drag event for this node, but I don't know how. I tried calling

```
d3.select( this ).on('.drag', null);
```

wihout results.

The other option is to subscribe each node to the `mousedown.drag` with this function:

```
function dragDecisor( d ) {
    if ( d3.event.ctrlKey ) {
        console.log( 'Draw a line...' );
    } else {
        console.log( 'Drag a node...' );
    }
}
```

But then I need to let the drag event to propagate, and it seems there is not a clear way to do this. I tried to create an event, as explained by **mbostock** (I cannot post more links, see d3 issue #100).

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I can now drag a node with ctrl pressed.

I mark a flag called ctrlPressed

```
function mousedown() {
  if (!mousedown_node && !mousedown_link) {
    // allow panning if nothing is selected
    vis.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom"), rescale);
    return;
  }
    //marking the ctrlKey press flag
  if(d3.event.ctrlKey){
      ctrlPressed = true;
  } else {
      ctrlPressed = false;
  }
}
```

Then in mouse move i added the condition to make and update the line if CTRL key is pressed

```
function mousemove() {
  if (!mousedown_node) return;
  if(!d3.event.ctrlKey){
        // update drag line
  drag_line
      .attr("x1", mousedown_node.x)
      .attr("y1", mousedown_node.y)
      .attr("x2", d3.svg.mouse(this)[0])
      .attr("y2", d3.svg.mouse(this)[1]);
  } else {
    mousedown_node.x = d3.svg.mouse(this)[0];
    mousedown_node.y = d3.svg.mouse(this)[1];  
  }

}
```

My working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/h003aywh/1/)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Cool! I didn't realize the second example was using d3 v2. With v3 I'm getting some problems, as it seems that I can't use the call function on the vis object. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: yeah true V3 has some issues which is beyond me to fix :)